# Find inverse of $a \mod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

If we want to find the inverse of $a$ mod $p$, $p$ not prime, then we can write
 $$ax \equiv 1 \mod p$$
$$ax+py\equiv 1 \mod p$$ and use the extended euclidean algorithm to solve for $x$, which is the inverse mod $p$

**My Question**
How do we find $x$ if $\gcd(a,p)\neq 1$

Comment: `if gcd(a,p)≠1` ...then there are no solutions (*why*?).

Comment: Is it because bezouts identity tells us that $ax+py\equiv r \text{ mod} p$, such that $r$ is a multiple of gcd$(a,p)$?

Comment: More directly, $\,ax \equiv n \pmod p \implies ax = kp + n \implies d = \gcd(a,p) \mid n\,$. Just write $\,a = a'd\,$, $\,p=p'd\,$, then $\,n = ax - kp = d \cdot (a'x-kp')\,$.

Comment: The modular inverse of $a \mod m$ exists **if and only if** $\gcd(a, m) = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are in the situation where $a$ and $p$ are both multiples of some $d>1$.

Two numbers which are multiples  of same $d$ (by positive or negative integers it is immaterial) will differ by at least $d$.

Getting an inverse for $a$ mod $p$ means finding $x,y $ such that $ax - (-yp)=1$.
As both $ax$ and $-yp$ are multiples of $d$ the difference of $1$ is not possible to achieve (as $d>1$ by hypothesis). Hence inverse does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

$ax+py=1$ must be true for some integer $y$...  but this means $\gcd (a,p)=1$

Comment: So gcd$(a,p)=1$ follows because if $ax+py=1$ where gcd$(a,p)\neq 1$ then we could factor some multiple $k \in \mathbb{N_+}$ out of $ax+py=1 \Longrightarrow k(a'x+p'y)=1$ which can't hold since $k(a'x+p'y) > 1$?  Is this correct?

Comment: Whenever $ax+py=1$ then, for a common divisor,  $d$, since $d$ divides the LHS, it follows that $d$ divides $1$...

Comment: This makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: See @dxiv's second comment under your question for the general rule...

Comment: This is an example of a linear diophantine equation...